# Magento 2 in default newsletter subscribe not working?

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, phtml, newsletter

> I will attached the phtml and php block code but client side mail does
>   not send?

**subscribe.phtml**

```
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title"><strong>Newsletter</strong></div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe"
            novalidate
            action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>"
            method="post"
            data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
            id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="field newsletter">
                <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
                                placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter your email address') ?>"
                                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe') ?>" type="submit">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe') ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Subscribe.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Newsletter\Block;

class Subscribe extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Retrieve form action url and set "secure" param to avoid confirm
     * message when we submit form from secure page to unsecure
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormActionUrl()
    {
        $checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($email); 
                    if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
                        $response = [
                            'status' => 'ERROR',
                            'msg' => __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'),
                        ];                        

                    }
        return $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
?>
```

Please help this task ???

Comment: Exactly what problem you are facing. Newsletter subscribed or email not sending ??

Comment: If you are on your local then emails wont send if you are not using any extension to send emails using SMTP.

Comment: i will added the SMTP extension but subscribe its not working

Comment: what error are you getting on newsletter subscribe ? Check its status in my account as well

Comment: In default 2.2.5 it is working. Which Magento version do you have ? Also what is the error on subscribing

Comment: Smtp Extension you are add and also set 25 port number for SMTP

Comment: i have added the SMTP extension. other mail sending function also working.

Comment: can you please share your error message?

Comment: Did you get any errors in the log file while sending an email? please use the try, catch method to find the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

it is simply your logic issue,

`$checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($email);`

Where you getting `$email`.

Also,

```
$checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($email); 
                    if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
                        $response = [
                            'status' => 'ERROR',
                            'msg' => __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'),
                        ];                        

                    }
```

**Is not right. Because of form action is `newsletter/subscriber/new`  and HOW will get the response from this URL to the current page?**

Comment: its not working Mr.Amit Bera

Comment: i need the home page subscribe and mail sending functions